# is there any good point to use 500 byte buffer for simple upper-case converter?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, buffer

I am reading programming from the ground up

in chapter 5,

the program uses 500 byte buffer for 1byte long character converting.

shouldn't it have to use double loop?

loop1 for read 500 byte by 500 byte from file.

loop2 for processing something in the 500 byte maybe a byte at at time.

and I think this make program little bit more complicated.

if I use a byte buffer for convert

there is nothing need but just one loop

loop1: read 1byte and processing it.

is there any good point to use 500 byte buffer for simple upper-case converter?

my development environment is x86,linux,assembly,at&t syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason to consider doing it 500 (or more) bytes at a time is that it may reduce the number of function calls into the library and/or Operating System services you're using for I/O.  I suggest you try it both ways and measure the performance difference for yourself.  Say your two versions are compiled to executables named ala `uppercase.`*version*, you can get a report on the CPU and elapsed time for it to run by typing the following at the shell prompt:

```
time uppercase.byte_by_byte < input > output
time uppercase.500_byte_blocks < input > output
```